# Decorating observable

Tags: java, rx-java, decorator, rx-java2

Is it OK to decorate `Observable<>`, `Single<>`, `Maybe<>`, `Flowable<>` in rx-java?
E.g. like this:

```
public final class NonEmptyStringSource extends Observable<String> {

    private final Observable<String> source;

    public NonEmptyStringSource(final Observable<String> source) {
        this.source = source.filter(s -> s.length() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(final Observer<? super String> observer) {
        this.source.subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Does this approach have some pitfalls?
Is it safe in use?

Comment: Streams have a 10k break even threshold. If your observable stream is smaller than that you will pay a performance penalty

Comment: Rx2 does not support null values, thus `s != null` would be redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike 1.x, this pattern in 2.x has no penalty and is almost like how the standard operators are implemented. Depending on your needs, you may want to implement an `ObservableTransformer` instead:

```
ObservableTransformer<String, String> t = 
    upstream -> upstream.filter(s -> s.length() > 0);

Observable.fromArray("a", "b", "", "d", "", "f")
.compose(t)
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against this, as it just obfuscates what is actually going on.

Just using `filter` inline is cleaner and more readable:

```
 .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
```

This comes from Apache Commons-Lang, but you can roll your own implementation just as easily.